# Flutter Hive Model Adapter of a model within a model

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

Using Hive in Flutter, I have to generate a Model Adapater by annotating my Model:

```
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'internet_connection.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 3)
class InternetConnection {
  InternetConnection({
    @required this.status,
  });

  @HiveField(0)
  ConnectivityResult status;
}
```

This fails and throws the Exception

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception:
> HiveError: Cannot write, unknown type: ConnectivityResult. Did you
> forget to register an adapter?

From what I can gather, I will need to do additional annotation to have the Model `ConnectivityResult` be seen by Hive. What additional logic would I need to provide to get around this?

Comment: Why are you using [hive] tag which is used for Apache-Hive - a DWH on top of Hadoop? You can create new tag for questions related flutter-hive. Please create your own tag. dart-hive or flkutter-hive, etc.